# C# - Why is there an error using EventHandler<T>?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Doing a Pluralsight video and can't find out why it's wrong.

**Error Message on this point:**

```
worker.WorkPerformed += new EventHandler<WorkPerformedEventArgs>(worker_WorkPerformed);
```

**Error Message:**

> Cannot implicity convert to type
> 'System.EventHandler<AB_Events.WorkPerformedEventArgs>' to
> 'AB_Events.WorkPerformedHandler'

**Snippets**

```
public delegate int WorkPerformedHandler(object sender,WorkPerformedEventArgs e);
public class Worker
{
    public event WorkPerformedHandler WorkPerformed;
    protected virtual void OnWorkPerformed(int hours, WorkType workType)
    {  
        var del = WorkPerformed as WorkPerformedHandler;
        if (del != null)
        {
            del(this, new WorkPerformedEventArgs(hours, workType));
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var worker = new Worker();

        worker.WorkPerformed += new EventHandler<WorkPerformedEventArgs>(worker_WorkPerformed);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void worker_WorkPerformed(object sender, WorkPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: `worker.WorkPerformed += worker_WorkPerformed;` ?

Comment: The Guy from the Pluralsight video makes it like i did and i would like to have an approach in this direction

Comment: I happen to have a subscription to PluralSight. Can you please share the link to the course you're following?

Comment: Module 3,Demo:Instantiating Delegates..                  
                https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=3b1cc21b-7460-4239-9940-f20bdd701010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i have done is to replace `WorkPerformedHandler`  by  `EventHandler<WorkPerformedEventArgs>`

```
public delegate int WorkPerformedHandler(object sender, WorkPerformedEventArgs e);
public class Worker
{
    public event EventHandler<WorkPerformedEventArgs> WorkPerformed;
    protected virtual void OnWorkPerformed(WorkPerformedEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkPerformed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

event subscription :

```
var worker = new Worker();
worker.WorkPerformed += new EventHandler<WorkPerformedEventArgs>(worker_WorkPerformed);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although methods and anonymous functions are implicitly convertible to a *delegate type* that matches their signature, a *delegate instance* is not implicitly convertible to another *delegate type*.

You need to use either `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` or your `WorkPerformedHandler`, but not both:

```
public class Worker
{
    public event WorkPerformedHandler WorkPerformed;
    
    //...
}
```

Or:

```
public class Worker
{
    public event EventHandler<WorkPerformedEventArgs> WorkPerformed;
    
    //...
}
```

Also, because `worker_WorkPerformed` can be implicitly converted to either type, the most concise syntax would be this:

```
worker.WorkPerformed += worker_WorkPerformed; // Implicit conversion
```

---

If you do go with your `WorkPerformedHandler` delegate, make sure you change the return type to `void` as per the signature of `worker_WorkPerformed`:

```
public delegate void WorkPerformedHandler(object sender, WorkPerformedEventArgs e);
```

It is generally not advisable to return from an event handler anyway, as there can be multiple subscribers.